# работа с запросами

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

```
 $categories = Category::find()->where(['id' => $id])->all();
```

как этот запрос сунуть в ассоциативный массив со всеми полями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```
$categories = Category::find()->where(['id' => $id])->asArray()->all();
```

[Ссылка на метод asArray()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#asArray()-detail)

Это первый вариант.

Второй вариант использовать для этих целей [ArrayHelper::toArray()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#toArray()-detail). Будет что-то вроде этого

```
$categories = Category::find()->where(['id' => $id])->all();

$categoriesArray = ArrayHelper::toArray($categories, [
    'app\models\Category' => [
        'id',
        'title',
        // the key name in array result => property name
        'createTime' => 'created_at',
        // the key name in array result => anonymous function
        'length' => function ($post) {
            return strlen($post->content);
        },
    ],
])
```

Answer (score 1):

[Документация. Документация. Документация](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#asArray()-detail)

```
$categories = Category::find()->where(['id' => $id])->asArray()->all();
```